# Sort a map with "MMMyyyy" as key

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, simpledateformat, treemap

I have a map whose keys are in MMMyyyy format and i need to sort based on month. 
input:

```
unsorted: {
 "Dec2010": 1,
 "Apr2010": 1,
 "Feb2010": 0,
 "Nov2010": 2,
 "Mar2010": 0,
 "Jun2010": 2,
 "Sep2010": 1,
 "May2010": 0,
 "Oct2010": 1,
 "Jul2010": 0,
 "Aug2010": 0,
 "Jan2010": 1
}
```

After sorting it should be like below:

```
sorted: {
 "Jan2010": 1
 "Feb2010": 0,
 "Mar2010": 0,
 "Apr2010": 1,
 "May2010": 0,
 "Jun2010": 2,
 "Jul2010": 0,
 "Aug2010": 0,
 "Sep2010": 1,
 "Oct2010": 1,
 "Nov2010": 2,
 "Dec2010": 1,     
}
```

Currently i am using treemap which sorts it in alphabetical order but how do i get it sorted based on month hierarchy.

Code:

```
    Map<String, Integer> unsorted = new HashMap<>();
    unsorted.put("Dec2010", 1);
    unsorted.put("Apr2010", 1);
    unsorted.put("Feb2010", 0);
    unsorted.put("Nov2010", 2);
    unsorted.put("Mar2010", 0);
    unsorted.put("Jun2010", 2);
    unsorted.put("Sep2010", 1);
    unsorted.put("May2010", 0);
    unsorted.put("Oct2010", 1);
    unsorted.put("Jul2010", 0);
    unsorted.put("Aug2010", 0);
    unsorted.put("Jan2010", 1);

    System.out.println("\nSorted......");
    Map<String, Integer> sorted = new TreeMap<>(unsorted);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sorted.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey()
                + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: Can you share whatever you have done so far?

Comment: I have updated the current sample code i am using.

Comment: Don’t store your months and years as strings in your map. Use proper date objects. In this case this would mean `YearMonth` objects. Only when you need to give string output, format the `YearMonth` into a string in the required format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try with a custom comparator:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMyyyy");

        Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                String s1 = (String) o1;
                String s2 = (String) o2;
                try {
                    return df.parse(s1).compareTo(df.parse(s2));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Bad date format");
                }
            };
        });

        map.put("Dec2011",1);
        map.put("Jan2011",0);
        map.put("Feb2011",1);
        map.put("Mar2011",0);
        map.put("Oct2011",1);
        map.put("Sep2011",0);

        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " -> " + entry.getValue());
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Jan2011 -> 0
Feb2011 -> 1
Mar2011 -> 0
Sep2011 -> 0
Oct2011 -> 1
Dec2011 -> 1
```

Comment: Thanks mzc, this is what i was looking for.

Comment: I think you can simplified to         Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>((o1, o2) -> {
            try {
                return df.parse(o1).compareTo(df.parse(o2));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Bad date format");
            }
        });

Answer (score 3):

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

## Java SE 8

```
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> unsorted = new HashMap<>();
        unsorted.put("Dec2010", 1);
        unsorted.put("Apr2010", 1);
        unsorted.put("Feb2010", 0);
        unsorted.put("Nov2010", 2);
        unsorted.put("Mar2010", 0);
        unsorted.put("Jun2010", 2);
        unsorted.put("Sep2010", 1);
        unsorted.put("May2010", 0);
        unsorted.put("Oct2010", 1);
        unsorted.put("Jul2010", 0);
        unsorted.put("Aug2010", 0);
        unsorted.put("Jan2010", 1);

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMuuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Comparator<String> comparator = (s1, s2) -> YearMonth.parse(s1, dtf).compareTo(YearMonth.parse(s2, dtf));
        Map<String, Integer> sorted = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
        sorted.putAll(unsorted);
        System.out.println(sorted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{Jan2010=1, Feb2010=0, Mar2010=0, Apr2010=1, May2010=0, Jun2010=2, Jul2010=0, Aug2010=0, Sep2010=1, Oct2010=1, Nov2010=2, Dec2010=1}
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

## Java SE 9

Java SE 9 introduced [`Map.ofEntries`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries-java.util.Map.Entry...-) which you can use to initialize your `Map<String, Integer> unsorted`.

```
import static java.util.Map.entry;

import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> unsorted = Map.ofEntries(
                                            entry("Dec2010", 1),
                                            entry("Apr2010", 1),
                                            entry("Feb2010", 0),
                                            entry("Nov2010", 2),
                                            entry("Mar2010", 0),
                                            entry("Jun2010", 2),
                                            entry("Sep2010", 1),
                                            entry("May2010", 0),
                                            entry("Oct2010", 1),
                                            entry("Jul2010", 0),
                                            entry("Aug2010", 0),
                                            entry("Jan2010", 1)
                                        );

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMuuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Comparator<String> comparator = (s1, s2) -> YearMonth.parse(s1, dtf).compareTo(YearMonth.parse(s2, dtf));         
        Map<String, Integer> sorted = new TreeMap<>(comparator); 
        sorted.putAll(unsorted);
        System.out.println(sorted);
    }
}
```

## Sorting & mapping using a single statement:

You can make use of the powerful `Stream` API (tutorials: [1](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html), [2](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html)) to get your job done.

```
import static java.util.Map.entry;

import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> unsorted = Map.ofEntries(
                                            entry("Dec2010", 1),
                                            entry("Apr2010", 1),
                                            entry("Feb2010", 0),
                                            entry("Nov2010", 2),
                                            entry("Mar2010", 0),
                                            entry("Jun2010", 2),
                                            entry("Sep2010", 1),
                                            entry("May2010", 0),
                                            entry("Oct2010", 1),
                                            entry("Jul2010", 0),
                                            entry("Aug2010", 0),
                                            entry("Jan2010", 1)
                                        );

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMuuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Map<String, Integer> sorted = unsorted
                                        .entrySet()
                                        .stream()
                                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                            e -> YearMonth.parse(e.getKey(), dtf),
                                            e -> e.getValue(),
                                            (v1, v2) -> v1,
                                            TreeMap::new
                                         )) // Returns TreeMap<YearMonth, Integer>
                                        .entrySet()
                                        .stream()
                                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                            e -> dtf.format(e.getKey()),
                                            e -> e.getValue(),
                                            (v1, v2) -> v1,
                                            LinkedHashMap::new
                                         ));
        
        System.out.println(sorted);
    }
}
```

Learn more about `Collectors#toMap` from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-).

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the answer is straightforward and quite simple using `TreeMap` and a custom `Comparator`

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Dec2010", 1);
map.put("Apr2010", 1);
map.put("Feb2010", 0);
map.put("Nov2010", 2);
map.put("Mar2010", 0);
map.put("Jun2010", 2);
map.put("Sep2010", 1);
map.put("May2010", 0);
map.put("Oct2010", 1);
map.put("Jul2010", 0);
map.put("Aug2010", 0);
map.put("Jan2010", 1);

Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(text -> YearMonth.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMyyyy", Locale.ENGLISH))));
sortedMap.putAll(map);

sortedMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

As suggested by [**Arvind Kumar Avinash**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10819573/arvind-kumar-avinash), here is an example using [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/)

The example is quite similar except it has an overloaded constructur accepting the source map as second argument

```java
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeSortedMap<>(
    Comparator.comparing(text -> YearMonth.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMyyyy", Locale.ENGLISH))), 
    map
);

sortedMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Both result in

```
Jan2010=1
Feb2010=0
Mar2010=0
Apr2010=1
May2010=0
Jun2010=2
Jul2010=0
Aug2010=0
Sep2010=1
Oct2010=1
Nov2010=2
Dec2010=1
```

Comment: Nice single-statement solution using Eclipse Collections! Is there a shorter way without using Eclipse Collections of what I've done using single-statement? I might have missed something.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67294152/convert-a-list-of-objects-to-maplong-list-using-streams/67307663#comment119083911_67307663) is another nice solution by Yassin where he has used Eclipse Collections.