# Convert a list of objects to Map<Long, List<>> using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert a list of Student objects to `Map<Long, List<>>` using `streams`.

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
list.add(new Student("1", "test 1"));
list.add(new Student("3", "test 1"));
list.add(new Student("3", "test 3"));
```

I want the final outcome in the following way:

Map

Key: 1

Value List: `Student("1", "test 1")`

Key: 3

Value List: `Student("3", "test 1"), Student("3", "test 3")`

I tried the following code, but it is reinitializing the `Student` objects. Can anyone help me fix the below code?

```java
Map<Long, List<Student>> map = list.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                Student::getId,
                                Collectors.mapping(Student::new, Collectors.toList())
                        ));
```

Answer (score 14):

You don't need to chain the `mapping` collector. The single argument `groupingBy` will give you a `Map<Long, List<Student>>` by default.

```
Map<Long, List<Student>> map = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getId));
```

Comment: Those id's look like `String`s to me :P

Answer (score 6):

The [answer by Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67294187/10819573) is spot-on. Just to add  to that, you can also use a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) e.g.

```
Map<Long, List<Student>> map = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getId, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 4):

For these kind of easy use cases, I prefer to look at [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) instead of relying on the overhead of creating a `Stream`.

The result is the same, it gives you a `java.util.Map` and I find the syntax more concise

```java
MutableList<Student> list = Lists.mutable.of();
list.add(new Student("1", "test 1"));
list.add(new Student("3", "test 1"));
list.add(new Student("3", "test 3"));

Map<String, List<Student>> map = list.groupBy(Student::getId).toMap(ArrayList::new);
```

Comment: This indeed looks very lucid. I had heard of this API but have seen it the first time in action through your answer.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash thanks, I think I'll answer more and more adding examples from this library, it is very good

Comment: After writing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67372448/10819573), I just thought to check with you whether it can be further simplified using Eclipse Collections API. If yes, please post the same for the benefit of future visitors.

Comment: Hi @ArvindKumarAvinash sure thanks for thinking about me, I'll check right away :)

Answer (score 0):

As alternative of `groupingBy` using `toMap`:

```
Map<Long, List<Student>> result = list.stream()
                                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getId,
                                                                s-> { List<Student> l = new ArrayList<>();
                                                                      l.add(s);
                                                                      return l;
                                                                    },
                                                                    (l1,l2)-> { l1.addAll(l2); 
                                                                                return l1;}));
```

Answer (score 0):

then answer provided by @Eran is straight forward but if you want to change the data type in this context `String` to `Long` then you can use `lamda expression` to convert `String` to `Long`

```
Map<Long, List<Student>> map = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s ->Long.parseLong(s.getId())));
```